# Return array as Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I need updateReferencedVersions to return an array

```
public openUpdateFlowsModal(item: ListItem): void {
    this.flowClientService.getVersionDetail(item.id).subscribe((version) => {
      const changeRefVersionCallback: IServiceMethod<UpdateItem> =
        (update: UpdateItem): Observable<UpdateItem> => {
          for (const newRef of update.newReferences) {
            this.flowClientService.updateReferencedVersions(
              newRef.idProject,
              newRef.idVersion,
              version.id
            );
          }

        };
      this.listViewDialogService.openUpdateFlowsDialog(changeRefVersionCallback, version.id);
    });
  }
```

For example, if I write like this:

```
return this.flowClientService.updateReferencedVersions(
              newRef.idProject,
              newRef.idVersion,
              version.id
            );
```

It will return just one element of the array but I need all of them

```
  public updateReferencedVersions(idProject: string, idVersion: string, updateIdVersion: string):
    Observable<UpdateItem> {
    return this.http.patch<UpdateItem>(this.getFlowStorageApiUrl() + '/versions/'
      + updateIdVersion + '/referenced-versions',
      {idProject, idVersion},
      this.apiService.httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: hi, we would need more context, which function should return what exactly? Do you mean for updateReferencedVersions to retunrn an array? then we would need its code to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Hello, yes I need updateReferencedVersions to retunrn an array.

Comment: I did it, thank you

Comment: so you want UpdateItem.newReferences as a output instead of UpdateItem?

Comment: Or do you intend to push the results of all the calls in your loop to be added into one array?

Comment: yes, i need to push the results of all the calls